# Declare a typedef with two types

Tags: objective-c, c

What I need is to declate a C function that takes in both an Objective-C 'id' type and 'Class' types as a parameter, but nothing else.

Consider:

void the_function(classorid theargument);

I thought of declaring a typedef to achieve this purpose... something that could either hold an 'id' pointer or a 'Class' value... I would then figure out what value was what with my C function.

So... is there any way (or type?) I can use that lets me achieve this goal?

Thanks. :)

Comment: So you want a single parameter that can be of either of two distinct types? Why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since classes are themselves represented by objects in ObjC, and `id` is the "generic object" type, you can in fact use `id` as the type for a pointer to a class. Defining your function with an `id` parameter will allow you to pass in both instances and `Class` objects. What you do with them inside the function (how you're going to distinguish them) is your business.

```
static void doThatThingYouDo(id obj) {

    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Class c = [NSString class];
        NSString * s = @"Rigatoni";

        id ci = c;

        doThatThingYouDo(c);
        doThatThingYouDo(s);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Sorry I cannot give you another +1 for "Rigatoni" :)

Comment: That's okay; its deliciousness was its own reward!

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

A union might help.

http://www.anyexample.com/programming/cplusplus/example_of_using_union_in_cplusplus.xml